# Is there a database of boundaries of cities/regions around the world?

Tags: data

I am looking for a list of boundaries of cities/regions around the world. I am interested in knowing for instance what the boundaries of a city such as San Francisco are.

Is there a database? I could only find center coordinates of the regions, but no data source that offers shapes of those regions.

Comment: The World Bank has various datasets [here](https://puma.worldbank.org/downloads) that may be worth exploring?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [online service](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) by OSM user Wambacher to select different levels of boundaries that are contained in the OpenStreetMap database, and download them by selection in various file formats. (OSM account needed for downloading from that server.)

There is no warranty that OSM data is complete in all areas of the world, but give it a try.

So the tree menu on the left screen side can be consideres as expandable list?

Answer (score 0):

EU in collaboration with Un-habitat came with harmonized approach of delineating city extents. You can check the UN habitat website under Data and analytics section for the updated city extents uploaded so far.